# Convert Featured products loop into Recent products loop?

Tags: php, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

Hello I have a page template I use for my home page, The website is a Wordpress website with a Woocommerce store.

I show featured products using this snippet of code and it works well within my layout and grid.

```
<div class="woocommerce columns-4 ">
 <ul class="products">
      <?php
          $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'posts_per_page' => 25,
              'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                        'field'    => 'name',
                        'terms'    => 'featured',
                    ),
                ),
            );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
 </ul><!--/.products-->
</div>
```

I wana duplicate this section and instead of the `'terms'    => 'featured'` I would like it to be `'terms'    => 'recent_products'`

However, are these *terms* like hooks? What would be the proper changes to pull in *recent products* instead of the featured ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much! (it says i have to wait 5 more min to award an answer)

Comment: What are those arguments called? Is there a list of them somewhere? All the available arguments?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the [documentation for WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).